# jquery infinity loop to slide imagebar over and over

Tags: jquery, loops, infinity

I want to make script to loop infinity so image will rotate everytime. This is my script which dont work:

```
function w_gore() {
  if(document.getElementById('mycarousel').style.top != '-544px' &&  document.getElementById('up').align == 'left') {
    document.getElementById('up').align = 'right';
    $("#mycarousel").animate({"top": "-=136px"}, "slow", function() {
        document.getElementById('up').align = 'left';
    }, setTimeout(function() {ruch();},1000));
  }
}

    function ruch() {
        w_gore();
    }

$(document).ready(function(){
    ruch();
});
```

Comment: What doesn't work about it? Script error? Stops early? Why do you have `<br/>` elements in your javascript code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already using jQuery, but not properly. Here are a few shortcuts:

```
document.getElementById('mycarousel').style.top
```

should be:

```
$('#mycarousel').css('top')
```

`document.getElementById('up').align` becomes `$('#up').css('align')`

`document.getElementById('up').align = 'right'` becomes `$('#up').css('align','right')`

You also need what *Samich* suggests.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `setInterval`:

```
function w_gore() {
  if(document.getElementById('mycarousel').style.top != '-544px' &&  document.getElementById('up').align == 'left') {
    document.getElementById('up').align = 'right';
    $("#mycarousel").animate({"top": "-=136px"}, "slow", function() {
        document.getElementById('up').align = 'left';
    });
  }
}

function ruch() {
    w_gore();
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    window.setInterval(ruch, 1000);
});
```

P.S. If you are using jQuery - use it in all your code parts.

**jQuery version:**

```
function w_gore() {
    if ($('#mycarousel').position().top != '-544px' && $('#up').css('align') == 'left') {
        $('#up').css('align', 'right');
        $("#mycarousel").animate({ "top": "-=136px" }, "slow", function () {
            $('#up').css('align', 'left');
        });
    }
}
```